# Prevent invalid input value change in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm trying to prevent the change in input value for two cases.

If there is

1. multiple negative sign **"-"** eg. prevent typing of **"-1-2-3"**
2. multiple **"."** value eg. prevent typing of **"1.2.3"**

For desktop browser, I'm able to achieve using the following functions.

```js
function valueEntered(element, event){
      var newVal = element.value
      if(event.code==="Minus") {
       if(element.value.length==0) return true // allow minus at start
        element.value = -1*parseFloat(newVal) // change the sign of number
        return false
       } 
       else if(event.code==="Period") {
        if(element.value.indexOf('.')>-1) return false
       }
      return true
    }
```

```html
<input type="number" style="border-radius: 5px;"  onkeypress="return valueEntered(this, event)" />
```

It's working perfectly fine. But if I use this snippet in android webview, it's not preventing as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I trusted https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code which tells that `event.code` will work for android webview also, but it doesn't.

Also `event.key` supports detecting numeric values only. If I type `-`, `.`,`,` ; the property `event.key` returns `Unidentified`.

Similarly, the property `event.keyCode` returns `229` for all keypress stated above.

So it is not actually possible to achieve what I want currently in android webview.